# Display shortcode content based on the chosen shipping method in WooCommerce cart and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, shipping-method

I'm trying to add a custom message based on the shipping method chosen by the customer. Using this code, I was able to do it. The only problem is that I should replace the text part with a shortcode.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping', 'ts_shipping_method_custom_notice' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'ts_shipping_method_custom_notice' );
function ts_shipping_method_custom_notice() {
    // HERE DEFINE YOUR TARGETED SHIPPING METHOD(S)
    $targeted_shipping_methods = array('local_pickup:3'); // Replace with the actual shipping method ID(s)
    // Get the chosen shipping methods
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    if ( ! empty( $chosen_methods ) ) {
        $chosen_method = reset( $chosen_methods );
        // Check if the chosen shipping method is in the targeted list
        if ( in_array( $chosen_method, $targeted_shipping_methods ) ) {
            echo '<tr class="shipping">
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">' . sprintf(
                    __( "a vit è na briosh", "woocommerce"),
                    '<strong>al 100%</strong>',
                    '<strong>' . WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode() . '</strong>'
                ) . '</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display a shortcode, you can use WordPress `do_shrotcode()` function in the code like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping', 'display_shipping_method_custom_notice' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'display_shipping_method_custom_notice' );
function display_shipping_method_custom_notice() {
    $targeted_methods = array('local_pickup:3'); // <== Define the desired shipping method ID(s)
    $chosen_methods   = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

    if ( ! empty($chosen_methods) ) {
        // Targeting the chosen shipping method
        if ( in_array( reset($chosen_methods), $targeted_methods) ) {
            echo '<tr class="shipping"><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">' .
            do_shortcode("[my_shortcode_here]") .
            '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tanks, unlike before there are no errors in the lines. But the content of the shortcode (a snippet like this: <script maps src="https://www.miosito.com/maps/mapsDropOffPoints.js" key="mysecretapikey123456789ebdf"></script>)
is not shown. Or it is shown for a few seconds. Strange: One of the variants I experimented with before writing my question also did this. Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Now I can't guess, and I don't know why, you get that issue with the JavaScript…

Comment: maybe I solved it. Apparently I can't use shortcodes that use the ID logic